# Why the environment variables shown by shell and jenkins different?

Tags: jenkins

I found the environment variables shown by shell and jenkins is different. When I see $PATH by echo, it shows as follows;

```
# cat /etc/passwd | grep jenkins
jenkins:x:998:997:Jenkins Continuous Integration Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash
# su jenkins
bash-4.2$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

However when I exec "echo $PATH" on Jenkins by (Build -> Execute shell), console log shows as follows;

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6923847933544830986.sh
+ echo /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Not only $PATH but many other variables are also different, but $PATH is important to execute command and I don't understand why they are not the same. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You should do `su - jenkins`.  `-` provides an environment which the user logged in directly.

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe your `user of shell` and `user who is building the job` are not same.
  run `$ whoami` command in your shell and jenkins (Build -> Execute shell).
- You can also set PATH variable in `Build -> Execute shell`  section or `jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> configure System -> Global properties` section. check the `Environment variables` then `Name: PATH`, `value: $PATH:/usr/local/sbin`.